# Not able to implement what I intend using toString and inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, tostring

Note:

From the answers I could gather that toString and inheritance aren't enough to implement what I intend. Please suggest an alternative implementation that will solve my use case.

```
public class A {
    String c;
    String d;
    A(String c, String d) {
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return c + d;
    }
}


public class B extends A {
    String a;
    String b;
    B(String a, String b, String c, String d) {
        super(c,d);
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + a + b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       B b = new B("a","b","c","d");
       A a = (A)b;
       System.out.println(a);
    }
```

}

The system out is printing 
cdab.

What I want is after the object b is cast to a, it should call A class's toString. So I want the output to be
cd.

Also,
I want b.toString() to return cdab. but ((A)b).toString() to return cd.

Comment: It is impossible in static-typed languages

Answer (score 3):

> What I want is after the object b is cast to a, it should call A class's toString.

That is not possible.

It is the object's *actual* type that determines the method that is called.  Casting does not change that, and neither does anything else.

If you want to be able to call `A.toString()` on a `B` instance, you must not override it.

Answer (score 1):

Casting an object to the type of its super-class has no effect. You can assign `b` to `a` without the casting.

`B`'s `toString` will be called anyway, since the method being called depends on the runtime type of the object for which it is called, which is `B` in your case. That's the way method overriding works.

Answer (score 1):

By keeping it simple you can say that no matter what `b` is after casting,  internally it's `new B("a","b","c","d");` and it will call `toString` of `B`. Now even after casting it to `A` it is calling `toString` of `B` because every `Mango` is basically `Fruit` but it will remain `Mango` forever.

Answer (score -1):

Funny question !

try

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.toString();
}
```

instead

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.toString() + a + b;
}
```

Comment: I want b.toString() to return cdab. but ((A)b).toString() to return cd.

Comment: See don't know what are you trying to achieve ! but when as cast object i.e   A a = (A)b; , Here Object 'a' becomes just a reference pointing object 'b' and indirectly calls all b's overridden methods.

Comment: My intent is clear. Read the question again. But yeah agree with you that inheritance and toString may not be the right way to implement it. If you have an alternate implementation that solves my use case, let me know.